# Convexity of Frobenius norm of matrix exponential

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, normed-spaces

I am trying to check if the following function is convex or not:

$$f(V) = \|A - BC(DBC)^{-1}\|^2_F$$

$$B=\exp\left( V F V^T \right)$$
$$F=\operatorname{diag}\left(f^1, \ldots , f^n\right)$$

where $f^i$ is a scalar for $i = 1$ to $n$ and $A \in\mathbb R^{n\times m}$, $D \in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$, $B \in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$, $C \in\mathbb R^{n\times m}$ and $V \in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$. I know that the norm is a convex function, but I am not able to check if the matrix inside the norm is convex/concave and increasing/decreasing. Any hints or directions will be much appreciated. Also, in case it is non-convex, is it possible to impose conditions on $V$ such that the function is convex.

Comment: Are $B,C,D$ invertible? Is $BC (DBC)^{-1}$ different from $D$?

Comment: $C$ and $B$ are not invertible but $D$ is invertible. Yes, $BC(DBC)^{-1}$ is different from $D$

Comment: Do you have _any reason at all_ to believe this is convex? Convexity is an extremely fragile property. It is the _exception_, not the rule. Furthermore, your [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2687322/convexity-of-the-frobenius-norm-of-the-product-of-matrices) examines a function which is similar in certain ways but simpler, and yet _it_ is nonconvex as well. Thus you should have no reason to believe this even more complex function is convex. It certainly obeys no composition rules that would assist in a proof, so the proof would have to come from first principles.

Comment: I am trying to build a convex function which solves a certain problem. If my function is convex I can use gradient descent to get a global minimum. Just curious, how should I approach the problem even if it is non-convex? The approach might be able to help me build a convex function. If it is non-convex, even then I can try to put some constraint such that the problem becomes convex. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelGrant My [other function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2687322/convexity-of-the-frobenius-norm-of-the-product-of-matrices) has two variables, but this one has one variable, so I thought even if it non-convex, I can get some constraints to make it convex.

Comment: That's just not how convexity works.

Comment: @DushyantSahoo I don't understand your comment. All matrices here are square matrices of the same sizes. If $(DBC)^{-1}$ exists, how can $B,C$ be non-invertible? As Jalex Stark says in a comment above, $BC(DBC)^{-1}$ is just $D$ and your $f$ is the constant function $f(V)=\|A-D\|_F^2$.

Comment: @user1551 My mistake, just edited the equation. They are not square matrices.